# sip stack for iphone and android

Tags: iphone, android, voip, sip, rtp

I am looking for the SIP stacks for Android and iPhone. I found plenty of similar questions, which are sometimes quite old... I do not care too much if the solution is commercial (but this is preferred) or open source.

So far I found

- Commercial solution from RADVISION for Android
- Open source SIPHONE for iPhone
- LINPHONE which covers both platforms.
- Gingerbreadhas built-in SIP stack - but seems that it has some limitations and
  might be removed by MNO...

My questions are:

1. Does anybody has good/bad experience with above solutions?
2. Do you develop and publish an application with use of above solutions?
3. Any commercial SIP stack provider for iPhone/iPad?

Thanks a lot
STeN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RADVISION, the company I work for, which you have mentioned offers its SIP stack also for iOS (which translates to iPhone and iPad).
Can't say how good it is (I can, but I don't think it matters what I think about our solutions), and we do have customers who have used our products successfully on these devices.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [pjsip](http://www.pjsip.org/).  It is very portable and is used by the Android application [CSipSimple](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/).

Comment: Hi, thanks - I was looking to the PJSIP web page and they are not mentioning the Android compatibility and I did not found the JNI wrapper.

Comment: I've used PJSIP for a number of projects and it's very good. What's truly amazing is the support you receive when you pay the license/maintenance fee.  These guys know SIP inside out, and you get answers within a couple of hours.

Answer (score 3):

For a commercial solution, have a look at the M5T SIP Client Engine from Media5. It runs on iOS, Android as well as PC and embedded platforms.

http://www.media5corp.com/en/developer-solutions/m5t-sce

Yes, I work there.

EricT

Answer (score 3):

I've found a real gem: [baresip](http://www.creytiv.com/baresip.html) ([github page](https://github.com/alfredh/baresip)). Extremely clean and clear. BSD-licensed. Highly portable: builds for [iOS](https://github.com/alfredh/baresip-ios), [Android](https://github.com/alfredh/baresip-android), ARM, and whatever. No support for Android hardware codec yet, though.

Our solution is not ready yet, but we're spending about 5x to 10x less time examining SIP framework sources than we did with alternatives. For now, we're extremely happy.

Not sure about commercial support, but the (small (yet)) [community](http://lists.creytiv.com/pipermail/re-devel/) and author are responsive and friendly.

Answer (score 2):

you can develop sip stack using Jain-sip-stack, which is open sorce and easy to understand the things over there

Answer (score 0):

TeleSoft ( http://www.telesoft-intl.com ) offers a SIP stack for Android and iPhone/iPad and also for Windows phones.  I think its a great solution, but then I represent the company, so that's not exactly an unbiased opinion.