# Android SIP stack - what to use?

Tags: android, sip, pjsip, jain-sip, mjsip

I need to create use an SIP stack on Android, which will work with asterix and will give users the possibility to change codecs (i need to implement G729 and some other codecs). I'm new in this field (voice and codec), and every bit of information will be appreciated. In my research across the Internet, I found the following SIP stacks:

1. [PJSIP](http://www.pjsip.org)
2. [MJSIP](http://www.mjsip.org)
3. [JAIN SIP](http://java.net/projects/jain-sip/)

What do you recommend to use for a commercial program? Or you can recommend some other? For my particular situation, it must support the G729 codec.

Comment: iam trying to use sip too , but my account was blocked from Asking Question here and i dont know How can i request to Unblock it , i need your Help here on Stack

Comment: I don't understand what do you need exactly?!

Comment: im lost , i need Stack Overflow for asking Questions about Sip , Android Etc ... But My Account was automaticly Blocked beacause i deleted my own Post and i dont know how to get Unbanned

Comment: Sorry i don't know how to help... :(

Comment: Take a look there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486099/sip-stack-for-iphone-and-android/21854684#21854684. Especially, I value baresip extremely highly.

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend also [Doubango](http://www.doubango.org/). It supports G729 as you would like, and there's an example project you can look into, which uses the framework - [ImsDroid](http://code.google.com/p/imsdroid/) - there's a lot of features already provided by ImsDroid and the source code is open.

Comment: Im new for ImsDroid, Can You please guide me how ImsDroid is working how can i implement this to my project?

Answer (score 7):

PJSIP is highly recommended. You can look at [CsipSimple](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/) which is an opensource Android phone using PJSIP and a good place to start. PJSIP supports a number of codecs including G.729 and speex, has small memory foot print and has extensive documentation.

Comment: PJSIP doest work on android and java straight off the bat. you must use JNI to convert the C library into java for it to become usable which is a pain itself.

Comment: JNI is easy if you know what you are doing. JNI conversion is part of CSipSimple. You don't need to do anything. When using JNI in Android apps try to use SWIG for JNI conversion. http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Android.html

Comment: I tried using SWIG to generate some JNI files but it doesnt work. it complains about missing header files dispite the header files and source code in C all under one location.

The CSipSimple project is not clear either.  how does it generate teh JNI files? where is all the SIPLib headers? .so .a or .c files?

Why doesnt CSipSimple simply generate a jar lib for pjsip? why is there no pjsip jar lib file?

Comment: Generating JNI headers using swig is straight forward. Just search on the web. I have compiled and used CSipSimple on my Android phone. It took me less than 20 minutes to compile and make a test call. The SIP lib headers are not in a single directory.

Comment: Hi John. i have already done a lto of search online and have also posted my own question about my issue and no one as answered so it cant be a straight forward as you think. If it was, there would be lots of guids on how to do it. the CSipSimple docs only explains how to build the whole project, not how you can create a jar lib file of sip and use it on your own app

Comment: @JohnQualis, would you be kind enough to modify your answer and add some JNI source code? It would be of great help to the entire community.

Comment: @jonney building pjsip is real pain. Still unable to build, this command is not working  `make dep && make clean && make` here are the logs https://paste.ee/p/O64gr can you please take a look and suggest what is wrong. I'm using cygwin on windows

Answer (score 2):

Although I have never tried this sdk for mobile development (but I can confirm its performance in the field of Windows VoIP SIP applications), I think this [android voip client](http://www.voip-sip-sdk.com/p_456-how-to-build-an-android-voip-client-voip.html) example can be also a possible alternative to the previously mentioned Android SIP stacks.

Answer (score 1):

I had to build a SIP app for work, currently we are using Linphone which can be found here https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android

It provides a ton of features from VOIP, Chat (text) Video Calls, remote provisioning, as well of a slew of codecs including G729. It does require compiling its C files to java and it takes a little bit for trying to get that to work. This can be done on Windows though it is a fair bit more work and you're better off to use Linux to this.

Answer (score 0):

As a fact, no sip stack will give you support for any specific codec. Codec integration always manual as like a plug in.

There is some open-source sip based projects as like [csipsimple](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/)  which has G729 codec integrated . If you study how they have added the codec then you will own able to add any codec in any other sip based frameworks.