# Android SIP Client

Tags: android, sip, voip

Which is the better way to start the SIP client for android using  any external libraries.Since the native inbuilt SIP libraries work only with versions greater than 2.3.1.Looking for the better and easier solution to build the SIP Client for lower versions of android.Could any one help with this...

Comment: check out the "How Do I ask Question" part here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask This will help you get more and various answers to choose from ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start implementing software SIP Client, you would need 3rd party SIP implementation stack. Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9787556/1007273) for a list of sip implementation stacks.

What to look for:

- evaluate the features you'll need and the features the sip-stack offers (they differ mainly in the supported codecs for audtio/video and the conference audio/video call support)
- pay attention of the latest release date of the sip stack implementation. Often "recent release dates" means better support and better features.

You will also see popular opensource software clients that use those SipStacks, which means the sources code is out there and you can see how they incorporate with the sipstacks.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [IMSDroid](http://code.google.com/p/imsdroid/) which works with WiFi, EDGE and GPRS. But the apk file is around 15-20MB.

Comment: Can you please guide me how can i Implement IMSDroid in my Project?