# How to make a audio and video call in Android using SIP?

Tags: android, sip

I want to start working  in audio and video call using sip in Android. I don't know about SIP.

What things we need to have first to start?

Comment: consult some sip based open-source projects refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13511372/voip-library-for-android/13511858#13511858

Answer (score 1):

Try linphone client, you really should read about SIP under wikipedia or try out some clients yourself. and not ask a question like this:

like what is a computer? why my computer couldn't turn on?