# VoIP android studio

Tags: android-studio, sip, voip

Hi I'm not very good with coding but I'm trying to learn as much as I can. I've been looking for tutorials on how to create an internet call app on android studio. So far I haven't found any. If anyone knows a process that could guide me I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VoIP library for Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13511372/voip-library-for-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use android's own implementation

[**Session Initiation Protocol**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html)

***from docs***

> Android provides an API that supports the Session Initiation Protocol
>   (SIP). This lets you add SIP-based internet telephony features to your
>   applications. Android includes a full SIP protocol stack and
>   integrated call management services that let applications easily set
>   up outgoing and incoming voice calls, without having to manage
>   sessions, transport-level communication, or audio record or playback
>   directly.

or other third-party libraries like following.

1.[Pjsip](http://www.pjsip.org/)
2.[Mjsip](http://mjsip.org/mjua.html)
3.[doubango](http://www.doubango.org/)
4.[belle-sip](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/belle-sip)

Hope it helps..

**P.S** taken from this [***answer***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13511858/6617272)

refer [***this also..***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15605924/6617272)

Happy Coding :)