# looking for a solution to add Video/Voice call with my existing app

Tags: android, ios, webrtc, apprtc

i am looking for a solution to develop video and voice call(like WhatsApp) ,is there any easy to integrate solution that can be integrate into both platform ios/android please suggest

Comment: Checkout is my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47117314/2437655) on QuickBlox integration.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [PJSIP](http://www.pjsip.org/) or [Customer360](http://customer360.co/?utm_campaign=StarterAugust&utm_medium=quora&utm_source=social)

[QuickBlox](https://quickblox.com/) also looks promising

Comment: thank you @moritzg is there any WebRtc based open source solution that works perfect with mobile apps ?

Answer (score 1):

There various 3rd party sdk available for that one of which is sinch the link is  [here](https://www.sinch.com/)
U can integrate it and make voice and video calls...

Comment: i need opensource solution can ,i can see sinch is not free

Comment: U can check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13511858/7951163) this might help u its open source ..

Comment: thank you Avinash , is there any other solution that use WebRTC instead of SIP