# How to integrate SIP with RTP into android?

Tags: android, sip, voip, rtp

I'm trying develop VoIP app which will connect SIP and RTP protocol and will have a function which in case  (for example too low capacity) hang a connection, change RTP codec and continue connection. For SIP I used  android sip demo example and this work pretty well. For RTP I thought about android.net.rtp but I didn’t  find a method which can measure  parameters of connections. Can you suggest a RTP library which is easy to use, it can be integrated with android.net.sip  and  allow to measure parameters  of RTP transmissions?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use another SIP client library and not the built-in one.
The built-in SIP clients has a lot of issues and it is a very basic/simple solution with lot's of limitation (The most obvious one, as you mentioned, it doesn't include RTP by default)

You can find more in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787556/android-sip-stack-what-to-use).